# Facebook finding out who friended who?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm designing a website that needs to figure out who initiated the friendship between a user and each of his  or her friends (basically, who friended who?).

I've been looking at both the Graph API and FQL, but cant seem to find a table with this information. The friends table of FQL seems to only have the UIDs of person 1 and person 2. What I need is ideally a third column which says which of the two people initiated the friendship (so who clicked the add friend button).

Is this possible to do? Any work arounds?

Comment: You should provide more details at what you tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details!

So I've looked in the friends table of FQL. But all I can see there is  the UIDs of person 1 and person 2. What I need is ideally a third column which says which of the two people initiated the friendship (so who clicked the add friend button). Does that make sense?

Comment: This information belongs into the question, so you should update it, so that people have a chance to know what you intend.

Comment: No, this is not possible. At least not for people who are friends already. (If they are not friends already, you could probably read their outstanding friend requests to see who send one to whom.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API does not return any information about previously-acceepted friend requests, neither who sent them nor when they were received
You can only retrieve friend requests sent to your app's users which have yet to be responded to